# mysql php UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

There's a strange problem here:

i have to write data from a CSV file into a mysql DB (default charset UTF-8)

when i read the CSV and print the query string on terminal (for debug purpose )the output is correct:

```
insert into orari (pv_id, day) values(5492, 'giovedì pomeriggio')
```

but when i run a select query with mysql client the result is weird:

```
*************************** 273. row ***************************
             id: 28856
             day: giovedÃ¬ pomeriggio
             pv_id: 5760
```

Same thing if i run the query on phpmyadmin.

The HTML output is correct, the charset is set to UTF-8 and the characters like àòù are correctly visualized.

*** Edit ***
This is my mysql charset and collation settings:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'c%';

| character_set_client     | utf8                                                  |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                                  |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                                  |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                                |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                                  |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                                  |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                                  |
| collation_connection     | utf8_general_ci                                       |
| collation_database       | utf8_general_ci                                       |
| collation_server         | utf8_general_ci                                       |
```

Comment: Are you sure your CSV is UTF-8?

Comment: yes, if i print mb_detect_encoding($string) after reading from CSV the result is UTF-8, and the echo $string output in terminal is correct (the terminal is for sure utf8:

Answer (score 3):

Each MySQL client should specify the charset they want when they handshake with the server. Unless overidden the default is `latin1`.

You can issue the following query on every connection to work around this:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
```

Or you can set it in the [MySQL charset configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) as described in the MySQL manual.

Comment: thx for the light speed answer. I have just tried to run SET NAMES 'utf8'; as a first query after the client connection but the output is the same...

Comment: Are you sure the CSV is actually UTF-8? You can try using [`mb_detect_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) to find out.

Comment: the result of mb_detect_encoding is UTF-8... is the insert query that change in some way the charset, beacuse just after this operation the insert query string is in UTF-8

Comment: This is a curious problem that I have never encountered before. Sorry.

Comment: thx anyway... the ridiculus things is that if i run utf8_decode on the string just before the read from CSV operation i get a weird terminal outoput,ai correct result from mysql client and a weird HTML output...

Answer (score 0):

You say that the HTML and the input is correct, but only `mysql` and `phpmyadmin` are incorrect.  You need to set the proper connection charset for these as well, since they default to `latin1` which means "8-bit clean, one byte per char".

(This shouldn't affect your problem, but you should make sure your table or column specify utf-8 storage.)

You'll notice your garbage output is two bytes, which means that what is stored in the DB is definitely UTF8. Your data is being misinterpreted on output.

For the `mysql` terminal program, start it with the `--default-character-set` parameter. Make sure it matches your terminal's character set.

I don't know how this is set with phpMyAdmin, but there should be a setting for connection character set as well.